# How to display current task and running clock in modeline

Tags: org-mode, mode-line

I started using org-mode's clocking commands for tracking how I spend time at work. While the clock is running, the current task is shown in the mode line, along with the title of the task, but only when I am in the agenda.

Can I somehow display this information in the modeline even if I am not visiting an agenda buffer?